# Javascript/Canvas - Create new images from preexisting ones?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm wondering if there's a way to take existing images and "stack" them to create a single asset in Javascript.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7paRZ.jpg

The above image album shows what I'd like to do.

Basically, for the game I'm making, I want to procedurally generate enemy NPC's and the like, drawing from a pool of different body parts. Each potential body part would have stats and a spritesheet attached to it, so when the character is randomly generated, I want to stack all of the necessary images together into a single asset that I can then use.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a very basic drawing API with the ability to draw a few basic shapes, strokes and fills. Other than filling with the background color, and/or clearing the whole canvas, there's no way to animate scenes with "sprites" or any complete objects sitting on top of each other, using only the basic canvas API. Copying images in is possible, but then you need to clear them every single frame and replace them, which is a lot of code overhead, if you want them to animate.

You should look into http://createjs.com or a similar "screen graph" type framework, something that sits on top of the canvas and lets you easily load up sprite sheets and move them around. It does the drawing, clearing, rotation, animation etc. of the canvas for you (basically making it a bit like Flash).

In terms of purely stacking or drawing on the canvas, yes you can grab an image and copy it directly onto the canvas using the context2d.drawImage method, but this is probably not going to achieve the effect you want by itself.

Comment: I'm using impact.js which handles the sprites themselves quite well, and I could easily have separate spritesheets for each body part, but it would probably hurt performance quite a bit to have to draw 6 separate images per character on screen per frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can build up your animation out of existing parts, if think the main issue is organizing the base artworks and having the drawing done to fit one with another.

Let's say :
You want an idle (line 1), walk (line 2), run (line 3)
on each line you have a constant number of frames, say 5.

Say also that your parts are : legs, body, arms, head.

Then you have to build the image by yourself, by stacking those images :

```
 function buildAnimation(legs, body, arms, head) {
    var resImg = document.createElement('canvas');
    resImg.width = legs.width; resImg.height = legs.height;
    var resCtx = resImg.getContext('2d');
    resCtx.drawImage(legs,0,0);
    resCtx.drawImage(body,0,0);
    resCtx.drawImage(arms,0,0);
    resCtx.drawImage(head,0,0);
    return resImg;
 }
```

then you can feed your game framework with this image, that will be used for an
animation.

The drawback of this method is that you have to draw all animations of all parts
at the same places each time.
   Issues : 
1) for the head for instance, you might not want to animate it.
2) you might want different height for different characters.
3) it's a lot of work !!

So you might decide of conventions to know where the parts should be drawn, and have
less part to prepare in an image, but a more complex way to build them.
   Short example : the file name of the image parts ends with their height, so you can retrieve them
easily. (bodyMonster48.png, bodyHead12.png, ...)

```
Writing everything would be too much work here, but just a short example :
```

say we have animWidth, animHeight the size of each anim, and five frames in each
of the 3 anims. Now we just have one head that we want to copy everywhere :

```
 function buildAnimation(animWidth, animHeight, legs, body, arms, head) {
    var resImg = document.createElement('canvas');
    resImg.width = legs.width; resImg.height = legs.height;
    var resCtx = resImg.getContext('2d');
    resCtx.drawImage(legs,0,0);
    resCtx.drawImage(body,0,0);
    resCtx.drawImage(arms,0,0);
    // copy the head in all frames of all anims
    for (var animLine=0; animLine<3; animLine++) {  // iterate in idle, walk, run
        for (var animFrame= 0; animFrame<5; animFrame++) { // iterate in images of the animation
            resCtx.drawImage(head, animFrame*animWidth, animLine*animHeight);
        }
    } 
    return resImg;
 }
```

To be able to build any combination with variable height, you'll
have to carefully parametrize everything, use file naming and positioning conventions,
and you'll surely need a whole helper class not to get lost in all combinations.